# IDE inserts incorrect #include statement

Tags: preprocessor, c++builder, custom-component, c++builder-2007

I'm working with Borland C++ 2007. My project group consists of a package and several projects that use a component within that package. When I use this component using the design editor, the IDE automatically inserts the required #include directive for the component. However, it does not include the correct path.

A workaround is of course to adjust the compiler's include path, but then I would have to do this for every single project which directly or *indirectly* depends on the component.

Does anybody know a better solution?

cheers
Hendrik

Comment: Update: I trying include_alias, but it doesn't seem to work:

Comment: #pragma include_alias("MyComponent.h", "..\CommonUI\MyComponent.h")